# All open intervals are equivalent with respect to cardinality means that $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to any open interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading a chapter on elementary set theory and it says:

> "Any open interval $(a,b)$ is equivalent to any other open interval $(c,d)$ by the function (...). Thus $\mathbb{R}$ as a set is equivalent to any open interval of real numbers."

If I find a $f$ bijective s.t. $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for *some* $(a,b)$, it is trivial.

But can I infer the assumption immediately, without finding such an $f$ ?  I don't know how to bring in the "infinite" characteristic of $\mathbb{R}$ to the bounded intervals.

Comment: You can explicitly show a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and a bounded interval. For example $tan(x)$ maps $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ bijectively. If you only knew that all bounded intervals are equinumerous and would like to show indirectly that the implies that they have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ you could do so by arguing that $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $(-n,n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and that $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}(-n,n)$, to conclude from there that $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality not more than any $(-n,n)$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are asking how to prove that there is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $(a,b)$ without actually defining such a functions. I don't see a way of doing that. On the other hand, $\arctan$ is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$. And it is easy to find a bijection between $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ and any interval $(a,b)$, and so…

Comment: Yes, I thought (maybe) there's a way to construct such a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(a,b)$ which "arises from" a certainly possible bijection between $(a,b)$ and some $(c,d)$, e.g. by stretching $(c,d)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (rather vague idea). Problem is, ofc, that one cannot translate fixed c,d boundaries to infinity in such a function